# How can I configure qBittorrent to automatically force resume stalled torrents?

Tags: download, qbittorrent, stall

Torrents sometimes get stalled when using qBittorrent. How can I configure qBittorrent to automatically force resume stalled torrents? I don't want to monitor myself which torrents are getting stalled. I use qBittorrent on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I haven't found so far any option within qBittorrent to force resume stalled or error-ed torrents, and if someone knows that, I'd appreciate to have it as well.
For the meantime, the only reliable way I found to do so is an AHK script:

```
Space::
{
    Loop, 100
    { 
        Send, ^+S
        Sleep, 2000
        MouseMove, 187, 118
        Sleep, 500
        Send, {LButton}
        Sleep, 60000
    }
    return
}
```

The MouseMove instruction that places your cursor to confirm the dialog should land on the "Yes" button on a 1080p monitor. In case you have another resolution, see the script that shows your current mouse position:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.


MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos 
MsgBox, The cursor is at X%xpos% Y%ypos%. 

; This example allows you to move the mouse around to see
; the title of the window currently under the cursor:
#Persistent
SetTimer, WatchCursor, 100
return

WatchCursor:
MouseGetPos, , , id, control
WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %id%
WinGetClass, class, ahk_id %id%
ToolTip, ahk_id %id%`nahk_class %class%`n%title%`nControl: %control%
MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos
ToolTip, The cursor is at X%xpos% Y%ypos%
return
```

For documentation or download see the official website: https://www.autohotkey.com/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly - 'stalled' means its unable to connect to any peers or seeds that have parts of the file(s) you don't have.

Since a 'stalled' torrent isn't active, if you have many torrents - it won't count as a currently active torrent for purposes of upload and download slots.

In theory - *if* you find a peer that has what you need and you have the download slots, it *should* automatically recover. Unfortunately generally when I've seen a stalled torrent - it very much isn't having any peers over an extended period of time

Basically automatically restarting *is* the correct behaviour if everything else is sorted.